# CPU usage on Heartbeat Cron (every minute)

Tags: magento2.2, cron

Magento 2.2: The heartbeat cron jobs that run every minute spike CPU to 100% for a second.   Is this normal?   I have other services running on my server (2 core 4MB Linode) and the Magento cron job is causing problems.

I installed Wyomind OE Scheduler so I can see what runs and there are no obvious errors or abnormalities.  I am not sure how to troubleshot beyond that.

I upgraded from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3 and saw no change.

Top Screenshot:
[image: top]

CronJobs:
[image: cronjobs]
<sub>(source: [parts-rescue.com](https://parts-rescue.com/ebay/galleries/Magento%202.2.2%20heartbeat%20cron%20tasks.png))</sub>

Comment: You can check for the **cron_schedule** table. Also login to SSH and type top command to check the top memory used resources.